# General method to find the oblique asymptotes to a curve

Tags: limits, asymptotics, analytic-geometry

All the books I've looked at say that if $y=mx+c$ is an asymptote, then the limit as $x$ tends to infinity is $y/x =m$.

So does that also mean that, as $x$ tends to infinity, $y$ also tends to infinity? (I think that it does because that is what makes an asymptote and this fact is used later in the question. If this is correct why don't we then write $m=\lim_{y\to\infty} y/x$?). **Edit please clarify this point because the comment says it's incorrect.**
I  couldn't write the question here so it's in the pictures below.

[image: My Method]
[image: The Doubt]

Questions:

1. Using my method, how can I find the $c$ in $y=mx+c$ after finding $m$?
2. **Why has the author first substituted $y=mx+c$ in the equation of the curve?** 
   *Edit: is it because the asymptote will touch the curve at infinity*
3. Why does the author say to equate the coefficients of the first $2$ highest degree terms of $x$ (i.e $x^n$ and $x^{n-1}$)?

Is there also some other way to solve this problem?

**Edit : The biggest problem is why Meadra substituted x=0 after substituting y=2x + c in the equation of the curve. She should have substituted x=0 in y=2x + c because the asymptote would cut the curve or intersect at x tending  to infinity so  at x is equal to zero curve will not be similar to the asymptote**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the debate down,I figured out the result this time

Consider the intersection of the surface $y^3 -6xy+11x^2y-6x^3+x+y$ with the $z$ plane we have the curve defined by  $y^3 -6xy+11x^2y-6x^3+x+y = 0(1)$.The function is defined implicitly so consider an asymptote to the curve it has the form $y=mx+c$ 
Dividing $(1)$ by $x^3$ and subsituting $y=mx+c$ We have

$$\displaystyle \frac{(mx+c)^3}{x^3} -6\frac{mx+c}{x^2}+11\frac{mx+c}{x}-6+\frac{mx+c}{x^3} = 0$$

Letting $x \to \infty$ we get. $12m=6$ Thus $m=2$

Thus the asymptotes are of the form $y = 2x+c$.Subsitute in $(1)$

$$3x^3 +12x^2c +6xc^2+c^3+12x^2+6xc+22x^3+11x^2-12x^4-6x^3c+x+2x+c=0$$

Now when $x=0$(I do this because since I subsituted the eqn of the asymptote in (1) the resulting equation varies the same way as the asymptote and to find the intercept we just let $x=0$) we get $y=c$ thus we have $c^3+c=0$ thus $c=0$

As a result the asymptote to the curve is $y=2x$

Comment: Ok after finding dy/dx =m  ,I get the same equation for m which gives m=1,2,3. But If in an example c is not zero how should I find it. I want to know how should I find c if it is not 0 in say another example. Also why has the author equated the coefficients of the first  2 highest degree terms of  x to 0

Comment: Answering your questions in order-No as x tens to infinity y doesnt tend to infinity e.g $ y=1/x$-Yes your logic is correct (multiplicative property of limis)

Comment: -As the function tends to infinity it behaves like the asymptote which justifies the sub-Equating the coefficients like that seems weird(are you sure you detailed it properly)-You also said solving for all m gives $c=0$ which is false (try $m=1$)-Finaly the equation you describe is a surface not a line so an asymptote to it is a plane.

Comment: Yes , I understand that as x tends infinity y will not tend infinity as in y=1/x but that's because xy=1 and y is inversely proportional to x . But here in y=mx+c , y is directly proportional to x. So as x tends infinity y should also tend to infinity. I was asking about this case not in a general way. In this case of ASYMPTOTES as x tends infinty y should tend infinity ? Secondly I had tried the method of differentiating but I could get only m from it not c.

Comment: Thirdly As the function tends to infinity (then as you said) it behaves as the asymptote then we should write the expansion for the above , because the expansion will precise tangent approximation. And No for m=1 c=0. 3mc^2 -12mc +11c =0 will give c=0 for any value of m beacuse it doesn't have a constant term.

Comment: Yes my bad if we equate that eqn to zero we have $c=0$  but equating coefficients like that makes no sense and is really wrong also further reminder the "function" you described is a surface not a curve so an asymptote to it (if it exists) would have the form $ax+by+cz+d=0$ not $y=mx+c$.

Comment: No the the function defined is not a surface . It's a curve only. Check at Wolfram Alpha. It is a curve not a surface and hence Asymptotes to it will be like ax+by+c=0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44809/discussion-between-meadara-and-shashaank).

Comment: yes off course .

Comment: I got it. It seems the best solution. Just one thing it was -6xy^2. and that would in the end give m^3-6m^2+11m-6=0 which would give all the values of m=1,2,3. Apart from that it seems a good solution. Just one thing more we know that the asymptote will be of the form y=mx +c. To find the intercept of the asymptote  we should substitute x=0 in y=mx +c and not substitute x=0 after substituting y=mx+c in (1). The solution is good but the conceptual doubt is that why have you substituted y=mx+c in (1) in the first place.That is like finding intersection points isn't it ? It's intersecting condion

Answer (score 1):

now solve for $m^3 - 6m^2 + 11m - 6 = 0$, you get three $m_1 = 1$, $m_2 = 2$, and $m_3 = 3$. Then, you have $y = x$, $y = 2x$, and $y = 3x$. Therefore, you have three asymptotes, which means that the oblique asymptote does not exist.

Comment: Ya in this case c=0 and there are no oblique Asymptotes but say in some other case in which c is not 0 , how should I find. Also in the 2nd picture why has the author equated the coefficients of the 2  highest degree terms of x to 0

Comment: But how should I get c